# Could not fetch the updated list of templates. Using the local cache. Check your proxy settings or increase the timeout

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I am trying install activator with play framework and this issue occurs:

` 
  C:\WINDOWS\system32>activator new
    Fetching the latest list of templates...

```
Could not fetch the updated list of templates.  Using the local cache.
 Check your proxy settings or increase the timeout.  For more details see:
 http://typesafe.com/activator/docs

  Browse the list of templates: http://typesafe.com/activator/templates
 Choose from these featured templates or enter a template name:
  1) minimal-akka-java-seed
 2) minimal-akka-scala-seed
 3) minimal-java
 4) minimal-scala
  5) play-java
 6) play-scala
(hit tab to see a list of all templates)
 >
```

`
But wifi internet is connected and worked well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my sugestion - remove actual play version and download other - newer. 
Of course add play path to your windows environment variables (I'm assuming you're usind windows)